# Problema ao subir Web Api em Asp.net core usando entity framework com postgresql

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Olá! Então, já mapeei minhas classes no banco, espelhei com sucesso e comecei a montar as funcionalidades do meu webservice. Com isso, me deparei com o seguinte erro:
 *InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'CadFuncionario.Interface.IFuncionarioRepositorio' while attempting to activate 'CadFuncionario.Controllers.FuncionarioController*

Segue meu controlador :

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Home")]
public class FuncionarioController : Controller
{
    private readonly IFuncionarioRepositorio _context;

    public FuncionarioController(IFuncionarioRepositorio context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Funcionario> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.ListarTodos();
    }

}
```

Meu repositório:

```
public interface IFuncionarioRepositorio
{
    //CRUDs Funcionario
    void Adicionar(Funcionario Func);
    void AttFuncionario(Funcionario Func);
    void DelFuncionario(int IdFunc);
    IEnumerable<Funcionario> ListarTodos();
}
```

A implementação da minha interface:

```
public class FuncionarioRepositorio : IFuncionarioRepositorio
{
    private CadFuncContext _context;

    public FuncionarioRepositorio(CadFuncContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Adicionar(Funcionario Func)
    {
        _context.Add(Func);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void AttFuncionario(Funcionario Func)
    {
        _context.Update(Func);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void DelFuncionario(int IdFunc)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Funcionario> ListarTodos()
    {
        return _context.funcionario;
    }
}
```

E o serviço, eu to adicionando assim:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<CadFuncContext>(opt =>
        opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Conn")));
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Estarei no aguardo ansioso por uma ajudinha rs

Comment: ele não consegue instanciar o `controller` porque precisa de um `IFuncionarioRepositorio context`. Acho que está fazendo uma confusão com repositório / contexto... e no seu controller, se vai usar um `FuncionarioRepositorio` precisa de passar um `CadFunContext` no construtor, e isso não está acontecendo.

Comment: Consegui! Foi +- isso, era na injeção das dependências mesmo, mudei o nome de algumas variáveis, redefini e foi!